# Having trouble installing Vidalia

Tags: ubuntu, gpg, tor

I am trying to install Vidalia on my Ubuntu 18.04 following this https://people.torproject.org/~sysrqb/webwml/docs/debian-vidalia.html.en

However `gpg --keyserver keys.gnupg.net --recv 886DDD89` returns

```
gpg: packet(13) too large
gpg: read_block: read error: Invalid packet
gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found.
gpg: Total number processed: 0
```

Also http://keys.gnupg.net/ has no keys for 886DDD89
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

This key is probably no longer being maintained and this is why it contains no OpenPGP data. From the [Tor FAQ](https://support.torproject.org/misc/misc-9/): Vidalia is no longer maintained or supported. A large portion of the features Vidalia offered have now been integrated into Tor Browser itself.